# Javascript passing and using that function

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var f1 = function(a){
    alert(a)
}

var f2 = function(data, method){
    method(data) // the problem is here, 
    // the method f1 is not called. Is there a way to call that method f1?
    // the method f1 might not be in this scope, the method f1 can 
    // be in a class or like this... 
}

f2(a, f1)
```

The question is: Is there a way to call that f1 from f2, from the passed method?
thanks

EDIT: this is some code I write here, but I miss to set the a. anyway the value of is 5.
EDIT: yes! it was just a tiny stupid error in my original code that missed up, i set the value after calling the method. hehe

Comment: What's `a`?  A quick test in firebug shows it works.

Comment: it won't do anything because 'a' is not defined. Otherwise it works.

Comment: of course, a has some value ***

Comment: now it works, thanks. This code was just an example of the actual code, so the value of a doesnt matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running your Javascript through a debugger. You'll get a message like `a is not defined` because the call `f2(a, f1)` is trying to pass a variable named `a` but you haven't declared one. However, this code will work:

```
var f1 = function(a){
    alert(a);
}

var f2 = function(data, method){
    method(data);
}

var a = 'this is a';
f2(a, f1); // results in alert('this is a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work fine.  In your example however, `a` is undefined when you make the invocation.  Make sure you define it; this could be the reason it's not working.

In other words, changing your example to:

```
f2(42, f1);
```

Will alert the number 42.

Comment: and i get: method is not a function